# Strange bug in +IE8

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this page via IE 8 or 9: http://sneakyrascal.com/starpons/about.html 
As seen there are two footers but in fact I only added one footer. I figured it's connected with `<a>` tag. when I remove it, it will work fine.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Am I the only one who read 'strapons'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open a new `a` instead of closing it:

```
<a href="images/Ruby_BIS_0011.jpg" class="iframe" ><img src="images/Ruby_BIS_0011-300x234.jpg" /><a>
```

You should have found this when using <strike>a</strike> *the* [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).